# Android New application creation

Tags: android

In New Android Application wizard,

Compile With is empty, nothing is populated in that combo box.. What is the problem? Help me please..

Answer (score 1):

In the SDK Manager, you need to download one or more "SDK Platform" items, corresponding to the Android versions/API levels you want:

[image: Android SDK Manager]

In the above image, you need to check items like "SDK Platform" under "Android 4.2" and then click the "Install" button on the lower right.

You may also wish to read the following pages from the documentation:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html
- http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html
- http://developer.android.com/sdk/exploring.html